# c++, что делает код?

Tags: c++

```
  const char *between = " .,:!?"; //Разделители между словами
  char s[100]="", *p;
  puts("Greq naxadasutyuny: ");
  gets(s);
  p = strtok(s, between);
  while(p)
   {
    if(strlen(p) > 3) puts(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, between);
   }
```

Объясните пожалуйста, как этот код работает, и чем собственно занимается?

Comment: Сто раз извинений, почему мне минусы скидываете, обясните хоть как-то, код не понял,  спросил , адекватно ответили, зачем мне минусы давать?

Comment: Минусы - за то, что вы просто содрали чужой код, не пытаясь написать свой, но при этом даже не потрудившись разобраться в чужом. *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух"*

Comment: Данный сайт предназначен в первую очередь для того, чтобы собрать базу знаний. Поэтому ценность для сообщества представляют конкретные вопросы, на которые поисковик мог бы привести человека с похожей проблемой. Вопросы типа "что делает этот кусок кода" в этом отношении абсолютно бесполезны для сообщества.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*По смыслу:*

Здесь вводится текст с клавиатуры, после этого он разбивается на слова, используя символы-разделители из `between`, затем выводятся все слова, длина которых больше 3 символов.

*По сторкам:*

```c
const char *between = " .,:!?";
```

объявляются разделители, которые могут быть использованы в тексте

```c
char s[100]="", *p;
```

объявляются два указателя, `s` для ввода текста, `p` для будущих токенов разделенного текста

```c
puts("Greq naxadasutyuny: ");
```

вывод подсказки для ввода текста

```c
gets(s);
```

ожидание ввода текста из консоли

```c
p = strtok(s, between);
```

инициация разделения текста на токены с помощью знаков разделителей из `between`

```c
while(p)
{
    if(strlen(p) > 3) puts(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, between);
}
```

вывод токенов, длина которых больше 3 символов

Comment: Спасибо друг.  От души